# Efficient way to limit the characters of paragraph (Vertical text-overflow)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to Create Blog page and thinking about best way to limit the length of the main content? (description under thumbnails)

I'm doing this with jQuery, but I'm looking for a common way that developers do it.

or I can limit it with php in backend.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // text limiter
    function textLimit(elements,maxTextLength) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            if (elements[i].innerHTML.length > maxTextLength)
            elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.slice(0,maxTextLength) + '...';
        }
    }
    
    textLimit($('.content').find('p'),200);
    
});
```

```css
div.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <a><h4>New Product</h4></a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder (or filler) text. It's a convenient tool for mock-ups. It helps to outline the visual elements of a document or presentation, eg typography, font, or layout. Lorem ipsum is mostly a part of a Latin text by the classical author and philosopher Cicero. Its words and letters have been changed by addition or removal, so to deliberately render its content nonsensical; it's not genuine, correct, or comprehensible Latin anymore. While lorem ipsum's still resembles classical Latin, it actually has no meaning whatsoever. As Cicero's text doesn't contain the letters K, W, or Z, alien to latin, these, and others are often inserted randomly to mimic the typographic appearence of European languages, as are digraphs not to be found in the original.</p>
</div>
```

thanks.

Comment: What do you really want to do, a fixed text limitation, or a way to prevent a user from writing more than the number of characters allowed per paragraph?

Comment: every post has own content and i want to display part of it in blog page under thumbnail image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. If you would like to show part of the content in a div, as you show above, it's best to use PHP:

```
$string = 'Put your text here...'

// strip tags to avoid breaking any html
$string = strip_tags($string);

// Max length = 200 
if (strlen($string) > 200) {

    // truncate string
    $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 200);

    // OPTIONAL: make sure it ends in a word
    $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'...'; 
}
echo $string;
```

I hope this gives you a better idea of your options!

Comment: thanks, whether Is this the way WordPress or common cms do it? (i'm not working with wordpress)

Comment: Yes, they are doing it server-side (PHP) too. Doing this client-side will make your source code very messy and easy for other people to play around with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS if the container has a fixed size

```css
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis">This is a dummy text to demonstrate ellipsis.</div>
```

Comment: i know it, i'm looking for multi line support, with no white-space: nowrap. thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe write height:max(font-size, line-height)*number-of-lines+vertical-paddings; overflow: hidden for the container

Answer (score 1):

For a client side solution I'd suggest [Introducing Clamp.js](http://joe.sh/clamp-js):

```js
$clamp(document.querySelector('.content p'), {clamp: '5'});
```

```css
div.content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js/master/clamp.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
    <a><h4>New Product</h4></a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder (or filler) text. It's a convenient tool for mock-ups. It helps to outline the visual elements of a document or presentation, eg typography, font, or layout. Lorem ipsum is mostly a part of a Latin text by the classical author and philosopher Cicero. Its words and letters have been changed by addition or removal, so to deliberately render its content nonsensical; it's not genuine, correct, or comprehensible Latin anymore. While lorem ipsum's still resembles classical Latin, it actually has no meaning whatsoever. As Cicero's text doesn't contain the letters K, W, or Z, alien to latin, these, and others are often inserted randomly to mimic the typographic appearence of European languages, as are digraphs not to be found in the original.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, great method but i hate of using people code. :) it will help me to do it well.